# Coloring the table with alternate color

Tags: php, html, css

Below i have added my css file and my html file i need to color my table with alter name color but its not working i don't know where i have done the mistake.

CSS FILE :-

```
table.gridtable{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float:center;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:groove;
    border-color:black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:600px;
    }
    table.gridtable th{
    border-width:1px;
    padding:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    }
    table.gridtable td{
    border-width:1px;
    padding:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    }
    .oddrowcolor{
    background-color: black;
    }
    .evenrowcolor{
    background-color: red;
    }
    table.gridtable td.darkcol{
    border-top:0px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    border-right: 1px;
    }
    table.gridtable td.emptycol{
    border-bottom:0px;
    border-right: 1px;
    }
```

HTML & PHP:-

```
 <table class="gridtable" id="alternatecolor" align="center"
 <tr><th>disease Name/th><th>Gene Name/th><th>OMIM Number</th></tr>  
 <?php
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("missensencemuttation",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select disease");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `gene_data` ORDER BY disease_name");
        $last=" ";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    

        $now=$row[2];
        if($last != $now){
                $rcnt=mysql_query("select count(gene_name) from gene_data where gene_name='$now'");
        if($rcnt==1){
        echo "<tr><td>";   
        echo "<a href='d1.php?d_name=".$row['disease_name']."'>".$row['disease_name'];
        echo "</a></td>";       
        echo "<td>".$row['gene_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ommi_number']."</td></tr>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<tr><td class='emptycol'>";   
        echo "<a href='d1.php?d_name=".$row['disease_name']."'>".$row['disease_name'];
        echo "</a></td>";       
        echo "<td>".$row['gene_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ommi_number']."</td></tr>";
        }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "<tr'>";
        echo "<td class='darkcol'>";   
        echo '&nbsp';
        echo "</td>";       
        echo "<td>".$row['gene_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ommi_number']."</td></tr>";
        }
        $last=$row[2];
```

can any one help me with this ??

Comment: could you post the html that is generated by your script? It's a bit hard to replicate your problem without having the database...

Comment: I don't see where `.oddrowcolor` and `.evenrowcolor` are referenced.

Comment: @patashu - Me neither... Nor do I see the start of the table (the `<table>` tag)? There is some information missing. There is a `class='emptycol'` and `class='darkcol'` statement - I suspect these are important but I don't see anything in their definition about color.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it looks like you want to apply `oddrowcolor` or `evenrowcolor` to alternating rows - but in your actual php/html, I don't see those class names anywhere. They're not being put on the rows, so their rules wont be applied. Just add them to the appropriate `<tr>` tags in your php and it should work. 
Alternatively you could use the `nth-of-type` selector to apply the rules without altering your php:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: black;
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I had never come across that syntax before. I'll wait to see if this solves the problem - but then you definitely get a +1 from me...

Comment: It's valid CSS3 syntax, supported by most (but not all) modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want alternate colors for each table row, then a simple CSS should do it. This way, if you want to insert new rows dynamically, it will adjust the colors automatically.

```
.stripped-rows:nth-child(odd){
   background-color:red;
 }
.stripped-rows:nth-child(even){
   background-color:blue;
 }
```

and html ...

```
 <table>
 <tr class = 'stripped-rows'>
     <td>sad</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class = 'stripped-rows'>
  <td>sad</td>
</tr>
 <tr class = 'stripped-rows'>
   <td>sad</td>
</tr>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6VeJH/)